# Possible to bookmark using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to create a bookmark without using the URL just the sqlite database?

im creating an android app , (library catalog) information from sqlite are can be viewed already. but i want to add a bookmark feature using sqlite and not url. 
Im new to this.

Can someone please help me out? Thank you!

Comment: Please add more detail about what you are trying to do.

Comment: All a bookmark(sic) needs is **something that is humanly recognisable** and **the location of what it points to**. So two columns for a very basic bookmark table. You could expand upon the location e.g. for a bookmark for books title, page perhaps paragraph. You could perhaps add a use count and order the bookmarks according to this in descending order to display the most commonly used.......